# AWS EKS fargate coredns ImagePullBackOff

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, docker-registry, aws-fargate

I'm trying to deploy a simple tutorial app to a new fargate based kubernetes cluster.

Unfortunately I'm stuck on ImagePullBackOff for the coredns pod:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason           Age                  From               Message
  ----     ------           ----                 ----               -------
  Warning  LoggingDisabled  5m51s                fargate-scheduler  Disabled logging because aws-logging configmap was not found. configmap "aws-logging" not found
  Normal   Scheduled        4m11s                fargate-scheduler  Successfully assigned kube-system/coredns-86cb968586-mcdpj to fargate-ip-172-31-55-205.eu-central-1.compute.internal
  Warning  Failed           100s                 kubelet            Failed to pull image "602401143452.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/eks/coredns:v1.8.0-eksbuild.1": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "602

401143452.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/eks/coredns:v1.8.0-eksbuild.1": failed to resolve reference "602401143452.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/eks/coredns:v1.8.0-eksbuild.1": failed to do request: Head "https://602401143452.dkr.

ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/v2/eks/coredns/manifests/v1.8.0-eksbuild.1": dial tcp 3.122.9.124:443: i/o timeout
  Warning  Failed           100s                 kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff          99s                  kubelet            Back-off pulling image "602401143452.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/eks/coredns:v1.8.0-eksbuild.1"
  Warning  Failed           99s                  kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   Pulling          87s (x2 over 4m10s)  kubelet            Pulling image "602401143452.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/eks/coredns:v1.8.0-eksbuild.1"
```

While googling I found https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-ecr-troubleshooting/
It contains a following list:

```
To resolve this error, confirm the following:

 - The subnet for your worker node has a route to the internet. Check the route table associated with your subnet.
 - The security group associated with your worker node allows outbound internet traffic.
 - The ingress and egress rule for your network access control lists (ACLs) allows access to the internet.
```

Since I've created both my private subnets as well as their NAT Gateways manually I tried to locate an issue here but couldn't find anything. They as well as security groups and ACLs look fine to me.

[image]

I even added the AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly to my EKS role but after issuing command `kubectl rollout restart -n kube-system deployment coredns` the result is unfortunately the same: ***ImagePullBackOff***

Unfortunately I've runned out of ideas and I'm stuck. Any help that would help me troubleshoot this would be greatly appreciated. ~Thanks

---

edit>

After creating new cluster via ***eksctl** as @mreferre suggested in his comment I get RBAC error with link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/troubleshooting_iam.html#security-iam-troubleshoot-cannot-view-nodes-or-workloads
[image: RBAC error]

I'm not sure what is going on since I already have
[image: Full policy on my IAM user]

---

edit>>

The cluster created via AWS Console ( web interface ) doesn't have the **configmap aws-auth** I've retrieved the configmap below using command `kubectl edit configmap aws-auth -n kube-system`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  mapRoles: |
    - groups:
      - system:bootstrappers
      - system:nodes
      - system:node-proxier
      rolearn: arn:aws:iam::370179080679:role/eksctl-tutorial-cluster-FargatePodExecutionRole-1J605HWNTGS2Q
      username: system:node:{{SessionName}}
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2021-04-08T18:42:59Z"
  name: aws-auth
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "918"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/aws-auth
  uid: d9a21964-a8bf-49e9-800f-650320b7444e
```

Comment: The first thing I'd check is whether the subnets you assigned to the Fargate Profile that matches the `namespace`+`tags` you are deploying with have a route to Internet. If they are private (and they should), make sure their routing table is such that it can go out to the Internet (via the NAT GW). You may also want to test deploying an EC2 on that subnet to check if it does have a route to the Internet or if you are missing something in the config.

Comment: Another thing you may want to try is to deploy a new EKS/Fargate cluster for test and comparison purposes using the `eksctl` utility (e.g. `eksctl create cluster --fargate`). This will create a dedicated VPC with a brand new EKS cluster with a Fargate Profile for the `kube-system` and `default` namespaces and coredns pods should start automatically. You could them compare your setup to this working one (that you apparently manually created) and see if there are specific differences.

Comment: @mreferre Hey, I've created the cluster using eksctl like you've suggested but I'm having some RBAC error now. Essentially I cannot see anything within the cluster. I've updated my post with some screenshots.

Comment: Yes this is due to the fact that the user you are logged in into the console is different from the user (or role) you have used to deploy the cluster with eksctl (see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/troubleshooting_iam.html) for how to fix that). It's probably easier to recreate the cluster using the access keys of the console user (this will give you access both at the CLI and Console without having to do anything).

Comment: @mreferre User is the same I don't have other users on that account only root. I've compared **configmap aws-auth** of both accounts ( one created via AWS console and another created using eksctl command and apparently the one created via AWS Console doesn't have simply doesn't have **configmap aws-auth** at all. I've updated my post and added the configmap that I've retrieved. -- Now I'm trying to figure out how to create such aws-auth configmap or modify it so it would allow the operations via AWS Console. ( well still that's just a guess at the moment )

Comment: Sorry about the troubles. FYI the user that installed the cluster [does not appear in aws-auth](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html). It's weird that if it's the same user you get access denied. PS using the `root` user is not a best practice, I suggest you create a separate admin user.

Comment: The EASIEST way to avoid these mismatches is to login in the console with your user (preferably not `root`) and launch a [CloudShell](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudshell/) to install/use eksctl. CloudShell will launch impersonificating the console user.

Comment: @mreferre Aaaaand creating non-root user and using it to create the cluster solved my RBAC problem as well as ImagePullBackOff... - If you want to create an answer and I will accept it. :) Thanks for help.

Comment: Cool. Happy it worked. I created a consolidated answer that tries to summarize this thread. Enjoy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating an answer to sum up the discussion in the comment that deemed to be acceptable. The most common (and arguably easier) way to setup an EKS cluster with Fargate support is to use [EKSCTL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started-eksctl.html) and setup the cluster using `eksctl create cluster --fargate`. This will build all the plumbing for you and you will get a cluster with no EC2 instances nor managed node groups with the two `CoreDNS` pods deployed on two Fargate instances. Note that when you deploy EKSCTL via the command line you may end up using different roles/users between your CLI and console. This may result in access denied issues. Best course of action would be to use a non-root user to login into the AWS console and use [CloudShell](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudshell/) to deploy with EKSCTL (CloudShell will inherit the same console user identity). {More info in the comments}